# Java.lang.String errors & not printing to error file

Tags: arraylist, vector, account, java

> For this project the end result was for there to be 2 error reports sent to an error file at as well as a listing of account summary information printed out. While i can get a majority of the account information printed out such as Balance before transaction and transaction to the account or if there were insufficient funds for the transaction, that's all that will print out as it should be. I'm receiving no errors or exceptions so i'm in all honesty not too sure where the issue at hand may be. I was hoping a second pair of eyes on my code could possibly point out where my issue may be, below is my code of the Account.java, CheckingAccount.java CreditCard.java and lastly D4.java which contains the main method.

**Account.java**

```
 public class Account {
     protected String accountNo, institution, name;
     protected double balance;

     public Account (String accountNo, String name, String institution, double balance) {
    this.name = name;
    this.accountNo = accountNo;
    this.balance = balance;
    this.institution = institution;
    }

    public String getAccount() {
    return accountNo;
    }

    public boolean debitAccount(double amt) {
    return false;
    }

    public boolean creditAccount(double amt) {
    return false;
     }
    }
```

**CheckingAccount.java**

```
public class CheckingAccount extends Account {

  public CheckingAccount(String acctNo, String name, String inst, double     balance) {
    super(acctNo, name, inst, balance);
    this.name = name;
    this.accountNo = acctNo;
    this.balance = balance;
    this.institution = institution; 

  }

  public double getBalance()
  {
    return balance;
  }


  public boolean debitAccount(double amt) {
    balance += amt;

    return false;

  }

  public boolean creditAccount(double amt) {
    balance -= amt;
    return false;
  }
}
```

**CreditCard.java**

```
public class CreditCard extends Account {
    private double creditLimit;
    private double availableCredit;
 public CreditCard(String acctNo, String name, String inst, double limit, double balance) {
   super(acctNo, name, inst, 0);
   this.creditLimit = creditLimit;
   this.availableCredit = availableCredit;
   this.balance = balance;

 }

 public boolean debitAccount(double amt) {

   balance -= amt;
   return false;
 }

 public double getCreditLimit(){
   return creditLimit;
 }

 public double getBalance()
 {
   return balance;
 }


 public boolean creditAccount(double amt) {
   balance += amt;
   return false;
 }
}
```

**D4.java**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class D4 {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
  {
    Boolean valid;
    String transactionFile = args[0];
    String theaccount, transaction;
    File transactions = new File(transactionFile);
    Scanner infile = new Scanner(transactions);

    File errorFile = new File(args[1]);
    PrintWriter error = new PrintWriter(errorFile);

    Vector<Account> account = new Vector<Account>();

    while(infile.hasNext())
    {
      transaction = infile.nextLine();
      valid = performTrans(account, transaction, error, errorFile);
   }
  }

  private static Account findAccount(Vector<Account> a, String acctNo) {
    for(int index = 0; index < a.size(); index ++)
    {
      if (a.elementAt(index).getAccount().equals(acctNo))
      {
        return a.elementAt(index);
      }
    }
      return null;
    }
  private static boolean Checkingacct(Account a)
    {
      if(a instanceof CheckingAccount)
      {
        return true;
      }
      else
      {
        return false;
      }
   }

private static boolean Creditcrd(Account a)
{
  if(a instanceof CreditCard)
  {
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }
}

private static String errorLog(Vector<Account> a, String transaction)
{
  String[] trans = transaction.split(":");
  String error;
  if(findAccount(a, trans[1])==null)
  {
    error = ("Invalid account: " + transaction);
    System.out.println(error);
    return error;
  }
  else
  {
    Account acc = findAccount(a, trans[1]);
    if( trans[0] == "debit")
    {
      error = ("Transaction denied: " + transaction);
      System.out.println(error);
      return error;
    }
    else
    {
      return null;
    }
  }

}

private static boolean performTrans(Vector<Account> account, String transaction, PrintWriter log, File errorFile)
{
  String[] pieces = transaction.split(":");
  String trans = pieces[0];
  System.out.println(pieces);

  if(trans.equals("create"))
  {
    if( pieces[1].equals("checking"))
    {
      CheckingAccount checking = new CheckingAccount(pieces[2], pieces[3], pieces[4], Double.parseDouble(pieces[5]));
      account.add(checking);
      return true;
    }
    else if (pieces[1].equals("credit"))
    {
      CreditCard creditCard = new CreditCard(pieces[2], pieces[3], pieces[4], 0, Double.parseDouble(pieces[5]));
      account.add(creditCard);
      return true;
    }
    else
    {
      System.out.println("not sure what to put here");
      return false;
    }
  }

  else if(trans.equals("debit"))
  {
    if(findAccount(account, pieces[1]) == null)
    {

      return false;
    }
    else
    {
      Account a = findAccount(account, pieces[1]);
      double amount = Double.parseDouble(pieces[2]);
    if(Checkingacct(a) == true) 
    {
        CheckingAccount checking = (CheckingAccount) a;
        System.out.println("Balance before transaction: " + checking.getBalance());
        checking.creditAccount(amount);
        System.out.println("Transaction to account: " + amount);
        System.out.println("Balance after transaction: " + checking.getBalance() + "\n");
        return true;
    }

    else if(Creditcrd(a) == true)
    {
      CreditCard creditCard = (CreditCard) a;
      System.out.println("Balance before transaction: " + creditCard.getBalance());

      System.out.println("Transaction to account: " + amount);
      if(amount + creditCard.getBalance() > creditCard.getCreditLimit())
      { 
        System.out.println("Insufficient funds for transaction");
        return false;
      }
      else
      {
        creditCard.creditAccount(amount);
        return true;
      }
    }
    }
  }

  else if(trans.equals("credit"))
  {
    if(findAccount(account, pieces[1]) == null)
    {
      System.out.println("Print Error Message");
      return false;
    }

    else
    {
      Account a = findAccount(account, pieces[1]);
      double amount = Double.parseDouble(pieces[2]);

      if(Creditcrd(a) == true)
      {
        CheckingAccount checking = (CheckingAccount) a;
        System.out.println("Balance before transaction: " + checking.getBalance());
        checking.debitAccount(amount);
        System.out.println("Transaction to account: " + amount);
        System.out.println("Balance after transaction: " + checking.getBalance() + "\n");
        return true;
      }

      else if(Creditcrd(a) == true) 
      {
        CreditCard creditCard = (CreditCard) a;
        System.out.println(creditCard.getBalance());
        return true;
      }
    }
  }

  else if(trans.equals("report"))
  {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
 }
}
```

The text file im attempting to read from is called D4.txt and the information inside of it is

```
create:checking:10-3784665:Chase:Joe Holder:2000
create:credit:1234567898765432:First Card:Bob Badger:4000
create:checking:11-3478645:Dime:Melissa Martin:1000
report
debit:10-3784665:523.67
debit:1234567898765432:3500
credit:10-3784665:50
credit:11-3478645:30
debit:10-839723:200
debit:1234567898765432:600
report
```

The two errors im supposed to be able to print out and see in the errorFile.txt or whatever you choose to call it is and is where the main problem is as this information for some reason is not being processed and printed onto the outputfle.

```
Invalid account: debit:10839723:200
Transaction denied: debit:1234567898765432:600
```

The information printed to the console is supposed to look like

```
Account Summary:

Checking account #103784665
Bank: Chase
Name on account: Joe Holder
Balance: 1526.33

Credit Account #1234567898765432
Bank: First Card
Issued to: Bob Badger
Credit Limit: 4000
Balance: 3500.00
Available credit: 500.00

Checking account #113478645
Bank: Dime
Name on account: Melissa Martin
Balance: 1030.00

End account summary.
```

But this is also a part of the issue as currently when i run the code whats being printed out to the console is

```
run D4 d4.txt errorFile.txt
[Ljava.lang.String;@1d540a51
[Ljava.lang.String;@b31c562
[Ljava.lang.String;@3db12bab
[Ljava.lang.String;@4ff0c6b8
[Ljava.lang.String;@4d40d320
Balance before transaction: 2000.0
Transaction to account: 523.67
Balance after transaction: 1476.33

[Ljava.lang.String;@2c9cc42e
Balance before transaction: 4000.0
Transaction to account: 3500.0
Insufficient funds for transaction
[Ljava.lang.String;@2bb07c61
[Ljava.lang.String;@483b594b
[Ljava.lang.String;@31470572
[Ljava.lang.String;@20aedee
Balance before transaction: 4000.0
Transaction to account: 600.0
Insufficient funds for transaction
[Ljava.lang.String;@2ea4aa4d
```

I know this is a lot of information to sort through and i just want to thank anyone and everyone in advance for your help and hope its something simple that im just overlooking!

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.